# Find time difference and distance between two Lat-Long pairs

Tags: mysql, haversine

I am trying to find the time difference ad distance between two lat long pairs.

I am getting incorrect values of time for a few records

```
SELECT A.ID, A.latitude, A.longitude, A.drive_time, (B.drive_time -     A.drive_time) AS time_difference, 6367 * acos( cos(   
            radians(A.latitude) )   
          * cos( radians(B.latitude) )   
          * cos( radians(B.longitude) - radians(A.longitude)) +   sin(radians(A.latitude))  
          * sin( radians(B.latitude) ) as distance  
    FROM mapper A INNER JOIN mapper B ON B.ID = (A.ID + 1);
```

Comment: Haversine gives you spherical distance, not time.  So what is the problem then?

Comment: I am calculating distance as well through this. But it gives syntax error. I hope to eventually calculate the speed for the data.

Comment: Show us the error/output.

Comment: In the question you say that the query gives you incorrect values. In the comment you say you get syntax errors. Can you pls decide what the problem is and give us a detailed error message or description in order to be able to help you?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: '1', '30.707250574082806', '76.70425552967978', '2016-06-21 11:50:57', '1.000000'  
'2', '30.70721125516585', '76.70434579817713', '2016-06-21 11:50:58', '1.000000'  
'3', '30.707278875443908', '76.70445968495817', '2016-06-21 11:50:59', '43.000000'  
'4', '30.707345005734997', '76.70457106229053', '2016-06-21 11:51:02', '0.000000'  
'5', '30.707413051843933', '76.70468566627726', '2016-06-21 11:51:02', '0.000000'  

Notice the time_difference for the 3rd record. It is incorrect.
Also the query for haversine distance shows syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found my solution.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.latitude, A.longitude, B.drive_time, 6371000 * 2 *     ASIN(SQRT(      
        POWER(SIN((A.latitude - abs(B.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),      
        2) + COS(A.latitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(B.latitude) *      
        pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((A.longitude - B.longitude) *      
        pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))  as distance     ,time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(B.drive_time,A.drive_time)) AS time_difference  
FROM mapper A left JOIN mapper B ON B.ID = A.ID + 1
```